# Is there a way to password protect a SQL LocalDB .mdf file in C# application?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I am creating a C# WinForms desktop application along with a SQL Server LocalDB database. I have a setup installer to install the application on desktop. Since it is not on the web server, I have to put the `db.mdf` file on the customer's computer. But then the user may try to attach this database to SQL Server installed in their own PC and access the data from outside the application. Is there any way I can password protect the file so that it can only be accessed from  the application?

I tried to change the extension of file so that it won't be oblivious that its an `.mdf` file but it does not work without `.mdf` extension.

Please help me if there is any way I can find a solution to this or any other database I can use for the purpose.

Comment: No, you cannot protect against someone with physical access. The best you can do is lock it against standard (non-admin) users, but even that can be worked around, and you wold need a shared LocalDB instance to make that work anyway. An admin user can definitely not be protected against: they can take ownership or get permissions of any files, as well as attach a debugger among others. Write a strong legal contract to prevent them messing around with it.

Comment: Thanks, just one doubt though can we find out if the database was modified from the application or from outside of application?

Comment: Well you could use triggers or SQL Audit, but both of those can be switched off by the user. You could check within the application that the schema matches what you expect, bubt even that won't stop someone determined with a debugger or a decompiler. Like I said, there is little you do to protect against this, other than making life a little difficult.

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for your help. I this possible in any other database like MySql?

Comment: No you would always have this problem. The only way to *ensure* the customer cannot mess with the database is to move it off-premises and serve it over a web server or similar.